# installing sage

Tags: package-management

I have installed the sage  binaries under Ubuntu 10.4. 
When I try to run sage I get the following:

```
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 1: ELF: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: ��
                                                                                   ����: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: CE��
                                                                                     :�
                                                                                       2b���K�������qXj�: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: /opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: 
                                                                : not found
���0: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: �: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: ��@�
                                                                                       : not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: : not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: H��s���H���5r: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 2: 8���: not found
/opt/sage-4.7.1-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.1_lts-x86_64-Linux/local/bin/python: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an updated version that was released, perhaps it might run better? http://mirrors.xmission.com/sage/linux/64bit/index.html The latest version was put up at the beginning of this month, it's: sage-4.7.2-linux-64bit-ubuntu_10.04.3_lts-x86_64-Linux.tar.lzma

Unfortunately, I no longer have a machine with 10.04 otherwise I would try running it to see if it worked for me.